# Large csv file not importing all rows in R while working on server?

Tags: r, csv, large-files

I have a large csv file of around 470 MB. Firstly I have tried to open this large data in my laptop which has a memory of 4GB in a csv format. But it raised an error/message that file not loaded completely. There were 1048576 rows that were opened.

I later tried to open the data in R using my university server using the following code:

```
library("sqldf")
postcodes = read.csv("ONS_Postcode_Directory_Latest_Centroids.csv", header =  TRUE)
```

But still, I have managed to open only the same number of rows. I was expecting to see all the entire number of rows with 60 column names for this data

How can you read the data along with its entire rows and columns in R?

Comment: You could try `library("ff")` as it suggested here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/opening-large-csv-files-in-r/

Comment: I have tried. I get an error message: Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got 'C1'

Comment: Have you tried changing those parameters: `VERBOSE=TRUE, first.rows=10000, next.rows=50000, colClasses=NA`?

Comment: Yes I did. But I get an error message: Error in UseMethod("recodeLevels") : 
  no applicable method for 'recodeLevels' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Comment: What is the error that R gives you about the file not opening completely, and did the server give the same error or the same behavior? How many lines are in your file?

Comment: The code in the question loads the sqldf package but then never uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use the data.table package and use fread to load the data